# React - How to add dynamic data to table from two uneven arrys

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dynamic, mapping

I have two uneven arrays and i want these two arrays to put into a table. I have tried following steps.

My first Array is like this. This array data also dynamic. Sometimes it has 5 but next time it will be 6 or 7. It depends.

```
var firstArray = [ "2019/01/01","2019/01/02","2019/01/03","2019/01/04","2019/01/05"]
```

This is my 2nd array. It has some information related to firstArray

```
var secondArray = [{RoomId:"RID1",Date:"2019/01/02","BookingID":"#111","BookingType":"ChannelManager","Status":0},{RoomId:"RID2",Date:"2019/01/01","BookingID":"#112","BookingType":"WalkIn","Status":1},{RoomId:"RID2",Date:"2019/01/04","BookingID":"#113","BookingType":"ChannelManager","Status":2}]
```

As you can see,Sometimes 2nd array doesn't have all dates indicated in firstArray. So i want a table like following.

[See This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLG31.png)

I have tried following steps.

```
<Table>
           <tbody>

           <tr>
           {this.state.isLoading ? <Loader active /> :
                this.state.firstArray.map(function(item, i){
                  return (
                      <td>
                    {item}
                  </td>                       
                  )
                })
                } 
            </tr>
            {/* data table row */}
            <tr>
           {this.state.isLoading ? <Loader active /> :
                this.state.secoundArray.map((item) => (
                  <td> {this.mappingFunction.call(this, item)} </td>
               ))
                } 
            </tr>
            </tbody> 
            </Table>
```

As you can see,I tried to send the secondArray to a function called mappingFunction and render the BookingID according to date, But it is not possible also. Can someone help me with this. 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebuild the data before rendering the table with `reduce` and `Map`

```js
function App() {
  var firstArray = [
    "2019/01/01",
    "2019/01/02",
    "2019/01/03",
    "2019/01/04",
    "2019/01/05"
  ];
  var secondArray = [
    { RoomId: "RID1", Date: "2019/01/02", BookingID: "#111" },
    { RoomId: "RID2", Date: "2019/01/01", BookingID: "#112" },
    { RoomId: "RID2", Date: "2019/01/04", BookingID: "#113" }
  ];

  const rebuild = secondArray.reduce((acc, { RoomId, Date, BookingID }) => {
      const idx = firstArray.indexOf(Date);
      if (acc.has(RoomId)) acc.set(RoomId, {...acc.get(RoomId), [idx]: BookingID});
      else acc.set(RoomId, {[idx]: BookingID});
      return acc;
    },new Map());

  const renderCells = (cellData) =>
    firstArray.map((e, index) => {
      const tmp = Object.keys(cellData).indexOf(index.toString()) === -1 ? "" : cellData[index];
      return <td>{tmp}</td>;
    });

  return (
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        {firstArray.map(e => (
          <td>{e}</td>
        ))}
      </tr>
      {[...rebuild].map(([RoomId, cellData]) => {
        return (
          <tr>
            <td>{RoomId}</td>
            {renderCells(cellData)}
          </tr>
        );
      })}
    </table>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></id>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're almost there. The thinking is correct but you just didn't implement it right. How about this?

```
return (
  <Table>
    <tbody>
      {this.state.isLoading ? <Loader active /> : firstArray.map(item1 => {
        const valueExistsInBothArrays = secondArray.find(
          item2 => item2.Date === item1
        );
        if (valueExistsInBothArrays) {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td>{valueExistsInBothArrays.Date}</td>
              <td>{valueExistsInBothArrays.RoomId}</td>
              <td>{valueExistsInBothArrays.BookingID}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        }
      })}
    </tbody>
  </Table>
);
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for trying to help me with this. But can you have a look at the attached image. It has the type of table i need. Your one is bit different. I think you can help me to achieve  what i really need. https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLG31.png

Comment: Yeah, just swap my generic table component out for yours. I was just highlighting a working example of the approach you were getting at. It's not a very efficient approach. You're probably better of with a reducing in a single pass but I wanted to show you that your thinking was correct and can work.

Comment: I updated the sandbox like with a slightly more efficient version of the same.

Comment: updated my answer to use your components as well. Hope this helps.